# Swagger 2 with Spring boot and interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm using spring boot 2.5.6, swagger2 and Java 17

I have an endpoint that receives a json with a JWT in the body like this

```json
{"signedPayload":"encodedJWTstring"}
```

As this JWT needs to be decoded, validated and its inner payload mapped to a DTO, we decided to create a Spring interceptor that would do that before reaching the Controller.
This part is working just fine, my only issue is with swagger.

```java
@Log4j2
@Component
public class CallbackInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
     // ...magic happens here...
     request.setAttribute(
        "decodedRequestDTO",
        CallbackRequestDTO.builder().build(); //and the fields set here too
  }
```

and the controller's method looks like this

```java
  public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> eventsCallback(
      @NotNull
      @Valid
      @RequestAttribute("decodedRequestDTO")
      CallbackRequestDTO callbackRequestDTO) {

  }
```

The problem I have, is that I can't find a way to change the swagger definition of the schema to the json I should receive and not the `CallbackRequestDTO`.
Apparently, the problem is that I'm using `@RequestAttribute` and because of that swagger won't scan other annotations such as `@Parameter`.

I've tried several combinations and annotations without luck, I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you using springfox or springdoc?

Comment: I'm using springfox